# Programatically Altering Font Face, Size, Weight & Color Of A Flex Label/Text Component

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, rich-internet-application

I can change the color of the label in Flex Builder, I can even BIND the color to a variable and that works, but I can't find the Color PROPERTY in order to change or reference it programatically!  What is the ActionScript 3.0 code to change the font or color of a piece of text in a Flex RIA - or is caring in what color your text appears too bizzarre a request for a RIA?  I wrote whole applications after just minutes of "learning" flex, how come it's taken me three days and I still can't change the color of my stupid label?!

Answer (score 6):

You're running into the difference between *properties* and *styles* (sometimes called *style properties* to confuse you).  For a UIComponent, `color` is typically a style.

In mxml, both are initialized as XML attributes; in Actionscript, *properties* are straightforward member variables, while *styles* are dealt with by the [StyleManager](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/styles/StyleManager.html).

In short, you set styles by calling [`UIComponent.setStyle`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/UIComponent.html#setStyle%28%29):

```
label.setStyle("color", 0xFFFFFF);
```